# SQL Query With Calculated MIN, Requesting Other Column Returns All Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, latitude-longitude, min

We have the query:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(SQRT(POW((100-x),2)) + POW((150-y),2)) AS distance 
FROM cabstands 
GROUP BY ID
```

to find out the ID of the closest point to the point 100, 150 in coordinate system. If I don't request the ID and try to get just the distance, the query returns the true value. However, if I request the ID (as in above query) it returns all the points, because of the GROUP BY. If I don't put GROUP BY, it simply doesn't allow me to execute the query by saying:

> ID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What is the solution to my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not to use `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY distance ASC`?

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Is this MySQL, or PostgreSQL perhaps?

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I am pretty sure it will work this way. I will let you know. And I've tagged my DBMS, I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2008, with Management Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, MIN(SQRT(POW((100-x),2)) + POW((150-y),2)) AS distance FROM cabstands GROUP BY ID ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Or for MySQL:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(SQRT(POW((100-x),2)) + POW((150-y),2)) AS distance FROM cabstands GROUP BY ID ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will accept your answer as soon as I try your solution, I am pretty sure that it will work :)